# Sitecore content editor - randomly adding iframe

Tags: iframe, content-management-system, sitecore

Recently when using the Sitecore content editor, I've noticed an iframe tag automatically appears in the HTML at the bottom of the content. This happens randomly, and when pasting plain text from another application and when typing directly into the editor. Does anyone know what is causing this and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it might be severals cases as below. please check if you are one of them.

1. One possibility is that you have a `browser extension` or `add-on` that is inserting the iframe tag. You can disable all of the extension or try a new browser to check if you are with the same problem.
2. Check if you have a `custom script` that is inserting the iframe tag.
3. Check if some Sitecore `plugins/modules` affected this by disabling/uninstalling them to verify it.
4. Try it in `HTML mode` instead of the Content Editor's `WYSIWYG` mode, sometimes it will bring in some uncertain tags when you copy/paste external content.

And a `screenshot` of the Editor or source code of the current page would be helpful to further dig into the issue.

Hope it helps.